# How to draw equal number of examples from each class in Scikit Learn SVM during training?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I used Scikit Learn to implement a [Support Vector Machine](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html). Since I am dealing with class imbalance (96% to 4%), I would like the SVM to draw an equal number of samples from each class during training. How can I achieve this with Scikit Learn?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be interested in [imbalanced-learn](http://glemaitre.github.io/imbalanced-learn/index.html) package which has a number of implementations such as oversampling and undersampling to tackle the class imbalance problem.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative approach is to adjust the class weights with the `class_weight='balanced'` argument; from the [SVC docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html) (similar argument exists for other SVM models, too):

> **class_weight** : {dict, ‘balanced’}, optional
>
> Set the parameter C of class i to class_weight[i]*C for SVC. If not given, all classes are supposed to have weight one. The “balanced”
>   mode uses the values of y to automatically adjust weights inversely
>   proportional to class frequencies in the input data as `n_samples /
>   (n_classes * np.bincount(y))`